How to test the ODCIAggregateMerge method in an Oracle user defined aggregator?
I have a user defined aggregate function in Oracle, and I want to test the ODCIAggregateMerge method, but I have the sense that it never got used in any of my scenarios (and that for over a decade). How can I make a simple test case that reliably forces the merge method to be used?

Have you tried queries having a "GROUP BY ROLLUP" ?

https://dbaora.com/oracle-user-defined-aggregate-function/
